# Angular JS links from directories above

Tags: javascript, angular

I've just found this weird looking issue. I run my angular app from the local server and gave my index.html file links from directories one level above it and program was unable to find them. My relative path looked like this:

```
<script src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Also when I run my app not from a server, just like a regular HTML file paths were correct. Is this a angular rule that files from directories above cannot be linked to the app. Or just I did something wrong?